Future Provider infinite loop
Actually I don't know with certainty what might be causing this infinite loop but I have tried my best to trace it down. So, I have this Notifier CalendarEventsNotifier that exposes a value of type CalendarEventsState through the provider calendarEventsNotifierProvider declared inside g.dart. file and listening to this state value inside the view MainCalendarView to determine the state of the view and update accordingly. The problem is when I try to read it from the view and access the method fetchCalendarEvents(CalendarEventsRepository? dependencies) through the notifier property it starts looping endlessly, it calls the service over and over causing the state to update and ultimately redrawing the view. Here are my classes so far:
Notifier
riverpod
class CalendarEventsNotifier extends _$CalendarEventsNotifier {
  @override
  CalendarEventsState build() {
    print('build method callled');
    return const CalendarEventsState.initial();
  }

  Future<void> fetchCalendarEvents(
      CalendarEventsRepository? dependencies) async {
    CalendarEventsState calendarState = CalendarEventsState(
        eventsItems: [], state: CalendarEventsConcreteState.loading);
    if (state.state == CalendarEventsConcreteState.loaded &&
        state.eventsItems.isEmpty) {
      state = state.copyWith(state: CalendarEventsConcreteState.loading);
    }
    final response = await dependencies?.fetchCalendarEvents();
    print('service called');
    inspect(response);
    if (response != null) {
      print('response not null');
      inspect(response);
      List<AppointmentViewModel> vmList = response.map((original) {
       final model = AppointmentViewModel(
            original.eventName,
            original.startDate,
            original.endDate,
            Colors.red,
            original.isAllDay);
            return model;
      }).toList();
      calendarState = state.copyWith(
          eventsItems: vmList, state: CalendarEventsConcreteState.loaded);
    }
    state = calendarState;
    print('method comepleted');
  }
}

Repository Provider
final calendarEventsRepositoryProvider = FutureProvider<CalendarEventsRepository>((ref) async {
final dataSource = ref.watch(calendarDataSourceProvider);
  return CalendarEventsRepositoryImpl(dataSource);
});

Main View
class MainCalendarView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MainCalendarView({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _MainCalendarViewState();
}

class _MainCalendarViewState extends ConsumerState<MainCalendarView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initial state');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print('did change');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    AsyncValue<CalendarEventsRepository> repository =
        ref.watch(calendarEventsRepositoryProvider);
        return repository.when(data: (data) {
          final state = ref.watch(calendarEventsNotifierProvider); 
          ref.read(calendarEventsNotifierProvider.notifier).fetchCalendarEvents(data);
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Builder(builder: (context) {
              inspect(state.eventsItems);
              if (state.state ==
                  CalendarEventsConcreteState.loading) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                    AppColors.bluePrimary,
                  )),
                );
              } else {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_Styles.mainHorizontalPadding, 0,
                      _Styles.mainHorizontalPadding, 0),
                  child: SfCalendar(
                    showNavigationArrow: true,
                    headerHeight: _Styles.headerHeight,
                    headerStyle: CalendarHeaderStyle(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: AppFonts.heavy,
                            fontSize: _Styles.headerFontSize)),
                    selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: AppColors.bluePrimary,
                        width: _Styles.selectorBorderWidth,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(_Styles.selectorCornerRadius)),
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    ),
                    view: CalendarView.month,
                    todayHighlightColor: AppColors.bluePrimary,
                    cellBorderColor: Colors.white,
                    dataSource: MeetingDataSource(state.eventItems),
                    initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                    monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
                        appointmentDisplayCount: 5,
                        dayFormat: _Styles.dayFormat,
                        agendaItemHeight: _Styles.agendaItemHeight,
                        //agendaViewHeight: height / 4,
                        showAgenda: true,
                        //showTrailingAndLeadingDates: false,
                        appointmentDisplayMode:
                            MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.indicator,
                        agendaStyle: AgendaStyle(
                          dayTextStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: AppColors.generalRedColor),
                          dateTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          appointmentTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: AppFonts.semiBold,
                              fontSize: _Styles.agendaItemBodyFontSize),
                        ),
                        monthCellStyle: MonthCellStyle(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: AppFonts.semiBold,
                            fontSize: _Styles.agendaItemBodyFontSize,
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }));
        }, error: (err, stack) => Text("$err"), loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
}

State
enum CalendarEventsConcreteState { initial, loading, loaded, failure, emptyList }

@freezed
class CalendarEventsState with _$CalendarEventsState {
  const factory CalendarEventsState({
      required List<AppointmentViewModel> eventsItems,
      required CalendarEventsConcreteState state,}) = _CalendarEventsState;

  const factory CalendarEventsState.initial(
      {@Default([]) List<AppointmentViewModel> eventsItems,
      @Default(CalendarEventsConcreteState.loading) CalendarEventsConcreteState state,}) = _InitialCalendarEventsState;
}

As I mention I'm not really sure from were to start so if I miss something please let me know. While debbuging I discover that when it finishes calling the service and updating the firs time it goes directly into the method in the  it goes directly into the method fetchCalendarEvents without any parent call in the call stack. I have also tried to use a FutureBuilder but with the same outcome.Any help is greatly appreciated this is really important.

I'm not really familiar with riverpod, so I maybe don't fully understand your code, but to me it seems that you are calling this fetchCalendarEvents inside the build, and then this method always changes the state, and a state change triggers a rebuild, which logical results in an infinite loop

repository.when will fire every time the build method is called, an so the data callback if repository is always an AsyncData, in which you call fetchCalendarEvents inside

The prblm is this part of your code
 final state = ref.watch(calendarEventsNotifierProvider); 
 ref.read(calendarEventsNotifierProvider.notifier).fetchCalendarEvents(data);

Let's break the prblm
final state = ref.watch(calendarEventsNotifierProvider); 

This part of code listen to change in provider and causes widget to rebuild with new value but after just executing it you change the provider
by using this:
 ref.read(calendarEventsNotifierProvider.notifier).fetchCalendarEvents(data);

So every time your provider changes and you listen to it using ref.watch(), in the next line you change the provider. This cause the infinite loop. That will never end
Change the provider value on some events like scroll, click not on widget build otherwise you will again face such prblm

Thanks for your help, I understand now the problem more clearly, but I have a question. According to business rules, this screen loads and triggers this method, there is no user interaction needed. would you know a way I could call this service without going into this conflict? because at first I try to modify the provider also in the didChangeDependencies()and initState() but was getting another error saying something like I was trying to modify a provider inside a method corresponding to the widget life cycle and that was not allowed.

If you want to fetch data on first load then in the notifier build fn where you defined the  the initial fn you can just directly call the api there. Then the notifier will be build with that as initial value. Check out this link which describe how to initialize a notifier with another provider in same way you can do it for async fns also
